# How to implement the method "lower()" on a list?

Tags: python-3.x, case-sensitive, lowercase

```
current_users = ["Bob", "RocK", "JeNNy", "Sara", "mike", "ROGER"]

new_users = ["rock", "Eliza", "MiKe", "roger", "StEve"]

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user.lower() in current_users:
        print("The name " + new_user + " is not available.")
    elif new_user.lower() not in current_users:
        print("The name " + new_user + " is available.")
```

What do I have to change in the code above in order to make all the names in the list `current_users` in the sixth and eighth line be lower case. I tried `current_users.lower()`, but an error occurs, `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'`.

To point out I don't want the names in the list `current_users` to change permanently. Only while the condition tests are in process.

Comment: Make a new list (or set) with all of the strings lower cased, then check in that?

Comment: Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of current users that is lowercase. You should also make it a set for better performance in membership-tests:

```
current_users = ["Bob", "RocK", "JeNNy", "Sara", "mike", "ROGER"]

new_users = ["rock", "Eliza", "MiKe", "roger", "StEve"]

current_users_set = set(name.lower() for name in current_users)

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user.lower() in current_users:
        print("The name " + new_user + " is not available.")
    elif new_user.lower() not in current_users:
        print("The name " + new_user + " is available.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the current_user list and if a match is found change the item to lower case see the sample code below. note it is untested

```
for new_user in new_users:
     for user in current_users:
         if new_user.lower() == user :
            user = user.lower()
            print("The name " + new_user + " is not 
            available.")
 if new_user.lower() not in current_users:
     print("The name " + new_user + " is available.")
```